# Do we have an API for getting invoice details of completed rides in uber?

Tags: uber-api

Any API for getting invoice for completed rides in uber? I have checked the uber API docs couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

For rider history, you could call the /history endpoint (https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/history-get) but this does not include fare details.

If your app is the origin of the trips, you can call /receipt endpoint for each trip via https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-receipt-get

If you are looking to get all trips including fare details and they are not coming from your app ID, unfortunately that is not available. "The receipt endpoint will only provide receipts for ride requests originating from your application. It is not currently possibly to receive receipt data for all trips."

For a non-api solution you can look at past trips including fare details in your app or on the web at https://riders.uber.com/trips. Hope this helps!